# VSCode extension use multi step input directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use the multi step input directly, for example user choose 
F1 - and start the steps to choose items.

Currently I found the following example, and remove the quickOpen and basic input

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/quickinput-sample/src/extension.ts

```
import { window, commands, ExtensionContext } from 'vscode';
import { multiStepInput } from './multiStepInput';

export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand('samples.quickInput', async () => {
        const options: { [key: string]: (context: ExtensionContext) => Promise<void> } = {
            multiStepInput,
        };
        const quickPick = window.createQuickPick();
        quickPick.items = Object.keys(options).map(label => ({ label }));
        quickPick.onDidChangeSelection(selection => {
            if (selection[0]) {
                options[selection[0].label](context)
                    .catch(console.error);
            }
        });
        quickPick.onDidHide(() => quickPick.dispose());
        quickPick.show();
    }));
}
```

However, when I start the extension I got the first step **multiStepInput** entry to choose, I want to **avoid it and start directly from the options to choose resource group,(from the example)**
How can I do it? 
I'm not able to omit the first (dummy) step when the user should choose the following,

```
    showQuickPick,
    showInputBox,
    multiStepInput,
    quickOpen,
```

As I directly want to use explicitly the **multiStepInput** and **not ask to choose it**

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/quickinput-sample/src/multiStepInput.ts#L24

I dont want to start from this

[image]

**I want to start from this**  when the user use F1

[image]

Comment: what happens if you call `multiStepInput(context).catch(console.error);`

Comment: @rioV8 - not sure I understand the context, can you provide please the all code? should it be in register command? how?

Comment: have you looked at the argument of the `activate` call

Comment: @rioV8 - yes I've tried many things....

Comment: Currently the first `options` are `const options = { multiStepInput, }`. If you don't want to show that step, set `options` the options you really want..

Comment: @MoshFeu - could you please add it as answer? the complite code that I put with the modification you did. thanks!

Comment: Sure :) My pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the first time options are `[multiStepInput]`

```js
const options = { multiStepInput }
```

If you don't want to show that step, set `options` as the options you really want 
of type [`QuickPickItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem))

Something like that:

```
commands.registerCommand('samples.quickInput', async () => {
  const options = ['vscode-data-function', 'vscode-appservice-microservices', 'vscode-appservice-monitor', 'vscode-appservice-preview', 'vscode-appservice-prod'].map(label => ({label}));
  const quickPick = window.createQuickPick();
  quickPick.items = options;
  quickPick.onDidChangeSelection(([{label}]) => {
    window.showInformationMessage(label);
    quickPick.hide();
  });
  quickPick.show();
})
```

[Screen Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da55e.gif)

**Update**
If you just want to skip the first quick input and start the `multiStepInput` right away, you can delete all the rest of the code in the command handler and just use this

```
context.subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand('samples.quickInput', async () => {
  multiStepInput(context);
}));
```

Which is equivalent to

```
options[selection[0].label](context)
```

Because `options[selection[0].label]` is `multiStepInput` when `multiStepInput` is chosen.

Comment: I try it but not sure how to use it with the context, can you please update with the code from my question ?

Comment: I want that the `'./multiStepInput'` will be called directly when I start this extension

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: Thanks 1+ , this is close :) , I want that the steps will continue the './multiStepInput' , and all the steps from './multiStepInput' file, just to omit the first selection. here you use only one step from the mutliple step example, I need them all just omit the first. thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer. The code is much simpler now :)

Comment: My pleasure :) BTW, I wrote a series of posts about variety of vscode APIs, you might find them helpful - https://medium.com/@moshfeu/comparefolders-visual-studio-code-extension-journey-intro-b540a0539629?source=friends_link&sk=db37e1889766ccd8fe553958a12a8f69

Comment: Greate will check it out :)